# filtrar registros por mês

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT dia, GROUP_CONCAT(hora) FROM marcacoes WHERE colaborador_id = {$colaborador_id} GROUP BY dia ");
```

Retorna a seguinte tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas quero que apareça só do mês 6 por exemplo, ele aparece de todos os meses.

Como faço pra exibir os registros que tenho no banco por mês?

Comment: só uma observação, não use mais "mysql_query", porque está ficando obsoleto. Use "mysqli_query", que além da query vai te pedir a conexão como parâmetro também

Comment: vc tem um campo com a data completa?

Comment: tenho sim, do tipo date (0000-00-00)

Comment: Na sua consulta o ano interessa? ou a consulta pode retornar registros de julho de 2015, 2014 etc?

Comment: Smoke Rohden, considere usar o mysqli conforme lhe falei, para que no futuro você não venha a ter problemas

Comment: uso o ano também, mas já consegui aqui cara muito obrigado ajudou bastante!

Comment: DiChrist vou considerar sim, valeu pela dica e muito obrigado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É necessario filtrar pelo mês e ano, pegue o campo que contém a data aplique um `month()` que retornar o mês data e `year()` que retorna o ano e faça a comparação com o valor desejado. A consulta deve ficar mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
SELECT dia, GROUP_CONCAT(hora) FROM marcacoes
WHERE colaborador_id = {$colaborador_id} AND month(campo_data) = 6
AND year(campo_data) = 2016 GROUP BY dia
```

Comment: rray, posso estar equivocado, mas essa condição do ano 2016 deve estar na query? porque vai que ele quer fazer um relatório de todos os meses de junho, comparando ano a ano. Isso pode ser muito útil para outras situações, como sazonalidade de produtos por exemplo.

Comment: @DiChrist o código para ser usado para marção de ponto de trabalho, se não colocar o ano ele vai pegar os registros de anos anteriores, imagino que ele queira somente do ano atual. Vou confirmar isso.

Comment: É, também aparenta para mim, ser horário de entrada, ida e volta pro almoço e saída. Mas como eu não tinha certeza, eu fiz essa observação.